# My Windows 7 64-bit laptop will not boot up

Tags: windows-7

This is exactly what it says

For Realtek RTL8101E/8102E PCI-E Ethernet cable controller v1.08 (080408)

PXE-E61: Media test failure, check cable

PXE-M0F: Exiting PXE ROM.

No bootable device -- insert boot disk and press any key

Here is another message i get

Windows has encountered a problem communicating with a device connected to your computer.

This error can be caused by unplugging a removable storage device such as an external USB drive while the device is in use or by faulty hardware such as a hard drive or CD-ROM drive that is failing. Make sure any removable storage is properly connected and then restart your computer.

Status: OxcOOOOe9
Info: An unexpected I/O error has occured.

I dont understand what happened. I was on the internet and then my computer was turned on(This makes me lose wifi) and i tried going to a different URL then my laptop went to this error screen. 
If you have any advice please tell me. Many thanks, Joseph Milo

Comment: Enter the bios, see if the hard drive is showing, it may have failed. Also check the boot device list, be sure network boot device is not first in the list, if it is move it down to the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

The media test failure / exiting PXE rom just means that you don't have a network cable plugged in, and that you're not doing a PXE boot. If you don't know what that is, trust me, you're not doing a PXE boot.

The underlying cause seems to be that whatever the computer is trying to boot up off of has disappeared. If it normally boots off of the harddrive, then the harddrive, harddrive controller, or harddrive connection is failing. Try unplugging the harddrive and plugging it back in again.